# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection : Vendor code 17002

Tags: sql

I have installed ORACLE SQL on my Manjaro Linux. But after restarting my PC getting below error in SQL developer:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 17002
```

I checked whetherr listener is running or not:

```
[akoley@animesh-pc ~]$ lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-AUG-2019 21:03:48
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=animesh-pc)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

I tried to start it too:

```
akoley@animesh-pc ~]$ lsnrctl start   
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-AUG-2019 21:05:15
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Starting /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...
TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/animesh-pc/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
   Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted
Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

My Listener file is this:

```
[akoley@animesh-pc ~]$ cat /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = animesh-pc)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Services.msc, right click Oracle...TNSLister into properties.  Set logon to Local System Account.  Restart it and get the status by running 'lsnrctl status' from the command line.

Comment: Linux doesn't have Microsoft Windows Service Manager...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173767)